# Submitting a form results to a url segment undefined in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I am setting up a simple form submission, when I submit the form the url becomes `undefined`
This is the view: `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/tours/categories`

```
router.get('/tours/categories', function (req, res) {
    res.render('agents/tourcategories', {
        page_link: 'wishlist'

    });
});
```

This is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard/tours/categories" >
    <div class="box_general padding_bottom">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Category Name</label>
                     <input type="text" name="categoryname" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g Hiking">
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-left" type="button" data- 
        dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button id="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I submit the form tne url changes to: `

> http://localhost:3000/dashboard/tours/undefined

```
router.post('/tours/categories',function (req, res) {
    console.log("We are here");    
    const category = new CategoriesDB({
        categoryname: req.body.categoryname,
        addedby: res.locals.useremail
    });

    // Save a Customer in the MongoDB
    CategoriesDB.save(function (err) { 
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }else{
             res.redirect('/tours/categories');
        }
     })
});
```

I realy dont know where the `undefined` came from, I have checked everything seems to be okay. It keeps popping up in the url everythime i submit the form

`

Answer (score 0):

From the snippets of the code you have posted, It might be because u have not used the middleware

```
router.all("/dashboard*");
```

But if u have used that and the GET request is working but not the POST then u will need to post more snippets of your code, mainly the middleware you defined to handle the routes

Comment: I think its csurf, I have removed it from my app.js, and suddenly everything works..... I think I'll make it specific on certain routes